# search and replace text in python

Tags: python, regex

I am kinda to python programming
I have no clue how to solve that task:

```
for line in f:  br
    m = re.search("f(\S+\s+,\s+\S+)", 
                  "56 - f(32  ,  6*3) + 62 * ( 54 - 3 ) + f(5  , 9+y)")
print m.group()
```

I have to convert all `f(x , y) to x*y`.
I haven't got an idea how to solve that. I tried with splitting but didn't worked.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand! what do you need to convert? the re.search string above? If so I would recommend a descent text-editor, vim is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a tour towards the python tutorial, perhaps the [string](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) section.

After that, the [regexp](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can be a complicated beast, I suggest reading up on them.  For this particular scenario [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) should do the trick.

Here's a sample of what I've come up with using the input you provided.

```
import re
inp = "56 - f(32  ,  6*3) + 62 * ( 54 - 3 ) + f(5  , 9+y)"

# Matches on characters, arithmetic operations, and digits (hopefully)
pattern = r"f\(\s*([a-z\d\-\+\*/]+)\s*,\s*([a-z\d\-\+\*/]+)\s*\)"

print re.sub(pattern, r"\1 * \2", inp)
```

This should produce:

`56 - 32 * 6*3 + 62 * ( 54 - 3 ) + 5 * 9+y`

I am no expert when it comes to regular expressions but hopefully the above will get you started.  I doubt the above regex will catch all occurrences and for that I suggest you ask someone with better regex-fu.  Merely providing this as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
regex = re.compile('a+')
x = re.sub(regex, 'd', 'baac')
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
bdc
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this!?

```
>>> inp = "56 - f(32  ,  6*3) + 62 * ( 54 - 3 ) + f(5  , 9+y)"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'f\((\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+)\)',r'\1*\2',inp)
'56 - 32*6*3 + 62 * ( 54 - 3 ) + 5*9+y'
```

probably its useful to put the multiplication in parantheses? Then you could use the following regexp:

```
>>> re.sub(r'f\((\S+\s*),(\s*\S+)\)',r'(\1*\2)',inp)
'56 - (32  *  6*3) + 62 * ( 54 - 3 ) + (5  * 9+y)'
```